# How do I set up a wireless LAN through my router

Tags: wireless, networking

The Main Issue is I would like to be able to use one or the other  / both of my laptops inter-dependently on a WLAN (wireless network?) how do I get the 2 different OSes to recognize each other?

OSes are Win Vista and Ubuntu 13.04

Router is a virgin super hub (UK)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, login to your router with the [steps in this website](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/ping/guides/routers/virgin-media-superhub-vmdg480.html).

What do you mean by `recognize each other`? Did you mean, you want to show up a shared drive from Ubuntu? For that you would need to use [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba).

Ubuntu has a guide on how to [setup Samba here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide).